# Error creating Campaign Member from flow

Tags: flow, campaign

I have a flow that adds contacts as campaign members to selected campaigns, which has been working fine for months.

We started getting an unhandled exception the other day. The debug gives me the following error:

`59 (59895668)|FLOW_ELEMENT_ERROR|INSERT --- INSERT FAILED ---  ERRORS :  (CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY) entity type cannot be inserted: Campaign Member, |FlowRecordCreate|Create_CampaignMember
14:32:19.093 (93092943)|FLOW_ELEMENT_ERROR|INSERT --- INSERT FAILED ---  ERRORS :  (CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY) entity type cannot be inserted: Campaign Member, |FlowScreen|Campaign_Member_Info`

Now, as a system administrator I can walk thru the flow and it works fine. However, if I login as a user and walk thru the exact same steps, I get the unhandled exception, which shows as the above error message in the debug log.

This was working fine just the other day for the same users? I checked their user account and they have the marketing user checkbox checked. Campaign object has read access and contact and leads have read, create and edit.

I haven't any luck narrowing down the issue or getting a more descriptive error.

Any ideas what I might be missing?

Thanks.

Comment: Check validation rules. Maybe one that limits who can create Campaign Members.  Or see if any fields from Campaign Member have been changed/removed so it is trying to insert data to a non-existing field.

Comment: @Dan thanks for your reply. I did check the validation rules and there are none on Campaign or Campaign Member. All the fields are still there two and haven't been modified since they were created. I wish I could get some more detail on the error so I could get some indication if it is a permission issue or something with one of the fields during the insert.

Comment: see http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/101442/2602

Comment: Just to check... have you pulled the setup audit log to see what changes might have happened since the error started?   As for the issue, if its working fine when you do it as an Admin there seems to be something around permissions (so it seems) that has changed.  I would focus on the delta between your Profile/User Record and the Profile/User Record of the Users with issues... interesting error, would love to be able to help further.

Comment: https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000jboQAAQ this might be the fix to the issue

Answer (score 0):

I suddenly started seeing a similar issue today (12/3/2016) on a VisualForce page that sets campaignmember fields. I debugged this by commenting out the Apex code on the controller action, and it still produced the following error:

system.security.NoAccessException: Create access denied for CampaignMember, controller action methods may not execute

When I removed the campaignmember form fields, the error no longer appears. This was working fine yesterday.